# WIX : Merge Module Issue

Tags: wix, wix3.5

When I try to use merge module feature in VS2010, I am getting an issue "Multiple Section entery"

Why i am getting this error?

I have done googling but I did not get any thread where i got my answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Module Id="ModuleTest" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">

    <Package Id='94290AA7-50E3-414E-A1BD-FC3C2B0C47D8' Description='My first Merge Module'
              Comments='This is my first attempt at creating a Windows Installer Merge Module'
              Manufacturer='TravelPort Private Limited' InstallerVersion='200' />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='MyModuleDirectory' Name='.'>

        <Component Id='MyModuleComponent' Guid='93F36B4B-B6E0-4000-8174-2660C0AE9D6A'>
          <File Id='readme' Name='ReadMeModule' Source='ReadMergeModule.txt' DiskId='1' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'></File>
        </Component> 

      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Module>

</Wix>
```

product.wxs file

```
<Product Id="ec20ec5e-bb50-45d0-9190-156cf146c8f3" Name="WinDemoApp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="WinDemoApp" UpgradeCode="979e03f4-3b50-43c1-9dde-dd675f726fde">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="WinDemoApp">
                <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            </Directory>

    <Directory Id ="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="WinDemoApp"></Directory>
    </Directory>

    <!--<Merge Id='MyModule' Language='1033' SourceFile='Module.msm' DiskId='1' />-->
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
<DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
  <Component Id="MyApp.exe" Guid="36AA7C63-ED57-40C6-8B14-843B9355C265">
    <File Id="MyApp.exe" Source="D:\WIXDemo\WinDemoApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"></File> 
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="EA549460-4D98-4B09-B621-D4F1AA12A617">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="WinDemoApp"
              Description="My Win Installer sample"
              Target="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]MyApp.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id ="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\WinDemoApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>


</DirectoryRef>
<!--<Icon Id="bug.ico" SourceFile="bug.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="bug.ico" />-->

<Feature Id="MyApplication" Title="WinDemoApp" Level="1">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this ComponentRef element and the Component above in order to add resources to this installer. -->
  <ComponentRef Id="MyApp.exe"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut"/>
  <!--<MergeRef Id="MyModule"/>-->
        <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 1):

The MyModuleDirectory directory element shouldn't have a name attribute.  Also your Merge element should probably be nested underneath the ApplicationProgramsFolder directory.  Where it's now it'll go to [ProgramFilesFolder].

Take a look at [Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML](http://iswix.codeplex.com).

Even if you don't want to use the tool, it's own installer is setup exactly the way you are setting up yours with merge modules consumed by a product.

Comment: New project page of the **Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML**: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix